# ReactNative Metro Bundler not starting

Tags: react-native

I'm starting to learn react native but i have a problem. I can't start a development server for us and print a QR code in my terminal. Here are the steps i do:

```
npm install -g create-react-native-app
create-react-native-app House-Share
yarn start
```

the following error appears to me:

> Running Metro Bundler on port 8081.
>
> Keep Metro running while developing on any JS projects. Feel free to
>
> close this tab and run your own Metro instance if you prefer.
>
> https://github.com/facebook/react-native

I have also tried to change the door but the same error always appears to me, I have done searches on google and stackoverflow but the suggestions made have not been effective.

Comment: `create-react-native-app` is now `expo`, so better start with expo!

Comment: dont close the current tab and open another tab and run react-native-run-android

Comment: thanks I solved it with the following commands:

npm install -g expo-cli

expo init myProject

cd myProject

npm start